# Why cant I just print the array and what are the conditions to avoid a loop?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, for-loop, printf

I wrote a program that changes the order of any given array and now I wanted to print it. Often, I just use a `for`-loop for integers, chars and all the other types, because it looks like that this works every time. Nevertheless, I am curious about the short version and I would like to know when I can use it. At the moment it just prints stuff from a random place.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int array1[] = { 4, 5, 2, 7, 5, 3, 8 };
    int laenge = sizeof(array1) / sizeof(array1[0]);
    printf("%d\n", laenge);
    int array2[laenge];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < laenge; i++) {
        array2[laenge - 1 - i] = array1[i];
    }
    
    printf("%d\n\n", array2);
    for(int j = 0; j < laenge; j++) {
        printf("%d", array2[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no built-in function for printing arrays (except for strings). There's no printf format spec for it. The loop is the correct way to do it, although you should put a delimiter between the elements, and print a newline at the end.

Comment: @Barmar so for loops will always work, no matter what type of elements are in the array?

Comment: Of course. You can do anything in a loop that you can do outside the loop. Just make sure that the format spec is correct for the array element type.

Comment: Well, you can write *a* [function](https://godbolt.org/z/bEM68fxGf) and call it multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Often, I just use a for-loop for integers, chars and all the other types, because it looks like that this works every time.

If the loop uses the correct iteration and the body converts the array contents appropriately to a valid stream, it should work every time.

> Nevertheless, I am curious about the short version and I would like to know when I can use it.

The only type of array for which `printf` has built-in support is arrays of `char`. If the array is null terminated, `%s` will print it, if it is not, `%.*s` can be used and the number of elements must be passed before the array pointer as an `int` argument.

Other types are not supported by default. Using a loop is the only portable solution.

> At the moment it just prints stuff from a random place.

`printf("%d\n\n", array2)` has undefined behavior because `%d` expects an `int` argument and you pass a pointer to `int`. `printf` will retrieve an `int` value from the place where the code would have provided an `int` argument, `array2` is passed as a pointer, possibly in a different place and with a different representation, so the output if any will be meaningless and the program could misbehave in other unpredictable ways.

Answer (score 2):

When you say,

> Nevertheless, Im curious about the short version and I would like to know when I can use it.

, I take you to be asking about this:

> ```
>     printf("%d\n\n", array2);
> ```

The short answer is "**never**".

A longer answer is that

1. the C standard library does not provide any functions for producing formatted output of whole arrays (except the various flavors of C strings as a rather special case), and in particular, `printf` does not provide such a facility; and
2. the particular `printf` call you present has undefined behavior, and even on its face does not mean what it sounds like you think it means.  It is attempting to print a *pointer* (to the first element of array `array1`) as if that pointer were an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "short version" - except for strings, there's no format specifier for `printf` that will print the entire contents of an array at once.

There are a couple of reasons for this:

- Arrays don't store any metadata about their size or type; when you declare an array like `int a[N];`, what you get in memory looks like

  ```
     +---+
  a: |   | a[0]
     +---+
     |   | a[1]
     +---+
     |   | a[2]
     +---+
      ...
  ```

  No storage is allocated for anything other than the array elements themselves;

  Under most circumstances, array expressions "decay" to pointers to their first element - when you called

  ```
  printf("%d\n\n", array2);
  ```

  it was equivalent to calling it as

  ```
  printf("%d\n\n", &array2[0]);
  ```

  What `printf` received was not the contents of the array, but only a pointer to its first element.  The `%d` conversion specifier expects its corresponding argument to be an `int`, so it will do its best to interpret that pointer value as an `int`, but the behavior is undefined and you can get anything from garbled output to having your program crash outright.

`%s` works for strings because it gets the address of the first character, then prints successive characters until it sees the zero terminator - its behavior is sort of like the following:

```
while ( *p )
  putchar( *p++ );
```

This won't work for arrays where `0` can be a valid, in-band value, and again arrays don't know how big they are at runtime.  So there's no good way to print the contents of an array with a single `printf` call.

That's just how C is.  There are valid reasons for why the language works this way, but it means you don't have those sorts of conveniences.